# Can the encoding of a document be declared using "charSet" instead of "charset"?

Tags: character-set

One of the websites I am working on declares ecoding of the HTML file using `<meta charSet="utf-8"/>` (notice the capital *S*) instead of `<meta charset="utf-8"/>`.

I am aware that this is not following the standard, but does it affects the correct interpretation of characters in the content? Must this be corrected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HTML attributes are case insensitive](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/documents.html#case-insensitivity) so, yes, you can do that. Running it through [the validator](https://html5.validator.nu/) would have shown you that, too.

Note: the [`<meta>` tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has.